Unable to Send Messages Using business_connection_id
As I understand it, to send a message through a business account, I need to specify the business_connection_id in the send_ method. However, I could only find this field in the UploadMediaRequest. Can you please advise how I can send messages using a business account, or is this feature not yet implemented? Thank you for your response!
I also thought that perhaps the GetBotBusinessConnectionRequest might help me with this, but it seems to only provide information about the connection.
